# RSA Scheme Prime Factorisation pq = n

Tags: factoring

Having some trouble simplifying this question given the below equations.
**Verify that using these formulas p*q = n**

n − φ(n) + 1 = n − (p − 1)(q − 1) + 1 = n − pq + p + q − 1 + 1 = p + q

assuming p>q, then
p − q = √(p − q)2 = √p2 + q2 + 2pq − 4pq = √(p + q)2 − 4n.

Then
p = ½ [(p+q) + (p-q)] and q = ½ [(p+q) - (p-q)]

Comment: Do you need to verify $p*q=n$? using what formulas?

Comment: Using the formulas I've given below the bold text. I believe I am required to simplify. To show that P*q = n from those equations.

Comment: Well, $n − pq + p + q − 1 + 1 = p + q$ isn't true unless $n=pq$. Is that what you're after? I would rather think it's the other way, though: Assuming $pq=n$ you should verify that the calculations are correct. That seems like a more probable exercise.

Comment: I suppose the intended task is: Given $n$ and $\phi(n)$ and the fact that $n$ is the product of two primes, it is computationally easy to determine the prime factors.

Comment: I believe Arthur's response is correct. Anyone agree?